# XML Schema (XSD) restrictions pattern for price

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am having a problem with restriction for XML Schema. Price must contain a float number between 0 and 1000, space and a 'euro', for an XML tag like this

```
<price>xxx,xx euro</price>
```

How should it look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex via `xs:pattern`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="price">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="\d{3},\d\d euro"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```